# SASS custom value isn't working on focus elements

Tags: html, css, sass, focus, extend

I am trying to add a focus styling to an element. However, I have ::focus and a class .focus. Since I'm using SASS thought it would be easier to create my own style value then @extend it to the two focuses to save on coding.

But whenever I write it, it isn't working and the styling just doesn't appear. If any one has any ideas as to why it would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Heres a small example of the code I've got.

```
%button-styling {
  color: $grey;

  %btn-focus { 
    color: $white;
  }
  
  &::focus,
  &.focus {
    @extend %btn-focus;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is ::focus? And what do your browser dev tools show you is the compiled and applied CSS?

Answer (score 1):

As [Sass docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors) said, **any complex selector that even contains a placeholder selector isn't included in the CSS ...**. So it is not meaningful to put `%btn-focus` inside `%button-styling` placeholder. For me these styles in a **scss** file work fine:

```
$grey: red;
$white: #FFF;
%btn-focus {
  color: $white;
}
%button-styling {
  color: $grey;
  &:focus,
  &.focus {
    @extend %btn-focus;
  }
}

button {
  @extend %button-styling;
}
```

And in your `html` you may have something like this:

```html
<div>
  <button class="focus">btn-focus</button>
</div>
<!-- or -->
<div>
  <button>btn-focus</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try putting the %btn-focus out side of the %button-styling but I still ran into the exact same issue? I can try it again. But is there any other reason that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Did you tried the exact code of me? Notice that you can't use ```button-styling``` as a class. It is not a class.

Comment: Yep tried it and it still doesn't work?

Comment: I'm using Dart-sass version ```1.26.5```. That code works correctly for me. You can put your own html or other related codes in your question to get better answer.